# removing hyperlinks in blogger post body

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, blogger

is there any way to disable hyperlinks in blogger posts or replace them with plane anchor text. i did find some code to change  hyperlinks from comments like but no results in trying to change it for post:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'/>
<script>$('.comment-content a[rel$=nofollow]').replaceWith(function(){return ($(this).text());});</script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `.comment-content` selector which is specific to the comments section if you want to select hyperlinks from the post you can try `.post-body`.

Something like this,

```
$('.post-body a').replaceWith(function(){
  return $(this).text();
});
```

It replaces the hyperlink with plain text, if you want to keep the anchor elements and just remove the href attribute try this,

```
$('.post-body a[href]').each(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```